# Monitoring a chatroom with Chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to monitor a chatroom with a selfwritten chrome extension. Because I don't know anything about the scripts behind the chatroom system itself, I thought about a simple timer and export script.

My idea is a periodical timer (let's say every second, because it has to react as fast as possible) calling a function, which reads the complete HTML of the current tab (with chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML) and sends the hole HTML to an external REST service (via XMLHttpRequest()).

I know that this approach is very ressource consuming, but that doesn't matter as all this will run on a dedicated computer. Of course I thought about using chrome.webRequest.onCompleted to trigger the export but, as already mentioned, i have no idea about the technical interna of the chatroom.

Unfortunately I can't find any API to create a time base on seconds, but only on minutes (chrome.alarms.create). Or is there a more elegant way to do this job?

Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

More elegant way would be to use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), at least as a source of a "there are some changes" event. But maybe the chat is implemented in such way that getting the changes (and then sending only changes, not the whole page) will be convenient too.